# Why do I get an ORA-00922 when trying to create a partitioned table in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, ddl, database-partitioning

I'm trying to create partitioned on oracle table but getting ORA-00922 error.

Error starting at line : 1 in command -

```
CREATE TABLE "RATE_REQUEST_BKP_PARIATIONED"
  (
    "RATE_REQUEST_ID"     NUMBER(10,0),
    "PRODUCT_CUSTOMER_ID" NUMBER(10,0),
    "DESTINATION_ID"      NUMBER(10,0),
    "CREATED_DT"          DATE,
    "CREATED_BY"          NUMBER(10,0),
    "MODIFIED_DT"         DATE,
    "MODIFIED_BY"         NUMBER(10,0),
    "RATE_STATUS_ID"      NUMBER(10,0)
  )
  PARTITION BY RANGE
  (
    CREATED_DT
  )
  INTERVAL
  (
    NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH')
  )
  (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-3-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY')),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-4-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY')),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-5-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY'))
  )
```

Error report -

```
SQL Error: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Table "RATE_REQUEST_BKP_PARIATIONED" dropped.

Commit complete.
```

Please help me finding out the issue with query.

Comment: The error report is saying different. If the DDL had errors, the table would not have been created. And the DROP also should have failed with invalid table name. Perhaps, something else in your DDL script is wrong.

Comment: Your code as posted creates a table. So whatever error you're getting, it does not come from the CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: Which version of oracle do you have?  10? 11?

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz has a good point. The INTERVAL syntax was introduced in 11g. However the post includes the line `Table "RATE_REQUEST_BKP_PARIATIONED" dropped.` which suggests that the table had previously been created successfully.

Comment: Please post your full script, because it looks like the error if not from the statement posted.

Comment: I was trying to create DB partition on Oracle 10g where as INTERVAL partition introduce for oracle 11g, i switch to oracle 12c and able to execute the above query. Thanks @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz

Answer (score 0):

May this Help you
If an invalid option is specified while defining a storage clause or column, ORA-00922 will be thrown.  ORA-00922 mentions that to specify that the column is not able to contain any NULL values, the valid option while specifying a column is NOT NULL, and solely constraints can follow the datatype.

Also notable to ORA-00922, which can also cause this error to be thrown, is that specifying a maximum length on LOG or DATE datatype.

Correcting ORA-00992 consists of correcting the syntax in your specifications, minding to take out the erroneous option or length specification from the storage of column specification

Answer got from this link
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00922_missing_or_invalid_option.htm